# Java Load From Reasource In Jar

Tags: java, file, jar, loading

I am having some difficulty loading files from resources in eclipse. In the IDE, loading works fine. In a compiled jar everything breaks.

This works for loading an image inside and outside of a jar:

```
ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("E.png"))
```

This works only in the IDE for a file object (I know it's messy):

```
File f = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Overworld.mp3").getPath().replace("%20", " "));
```

I was hoping that there was a constructor for a file object File(InputStream) so I could use the first method of loading an image (which works flawlessly so far) for a file. This, however doesn't exist.

Is there any other method of loading a file into a file object in such a way that it works in the IDE and in a compiled jar?

Thanks in advance.

(Separate but related question: why does `File f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("Overworld.mp3").getFile());` give a MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE exception? The file is in the same package as "E.png" with all other source files in my project)

Comment: A file represents more than just data - it also has a location, possibly a mime type, visibility, etc. It makes sense that you can't just create a file from a stream, you have to specifiy a bit more than that. But it seems like you don't need this information, so why do you need a File?

Comment: URL.getFile() *does not* convert a URL to a file name.  It just returns the portion of the URL after the host, with all percent encodings (which is more than just "%20").  Attempting to create a File from a resource URL is always wrong.  Read from the URL itself, or use `getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream()` returns a `java.io.InputStream` that you can use to read the contents of a resource in a jar as a byte array.

Will this work for you?

Why do you require a `java.io.File`?

Comment: This does work for me. I don't know why I didn't do this earlier (probably skimmed too quickly over the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to load resource that placed with your class/jar.

> URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);